# Not able to get HTMLElement and its value in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

> I am developing a component in which data is come from Servlet and set
>   in the labels of component.I am successfully set the data on the
>   labels. but not able to access the html elements or that labels value
>   and set it on popup dialog. getting null when i check it in console.
>
> createComponent() will set the parameters , then it call the
>   createLayout and in layout on the click events i called the edit
>   window method.and there i am not able to find element.I have tried
>   with html and text method too but not working.so i just switched to js
>   and tried it.but not get success
>
> I AM GETTING LABELS IN setData() METHOD BUT NOT IN >getEditWindow()..PLEASE HELP ME TO SOLVE THE IT

```js
/*var timeout_ = setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 30000);*/

var a = randNum();
var timeout=[];

(function($) {




    $.fn.createComponent = function(options) {

        var req_divId = this.attr('id');
        var b=a;
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            url : null,
            separator : null,
            lableTag : ['Block 1','Block 2','block 3','block 4'],
            color : 'lavender'
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            if (settings.url != null && settings.separator != null) {

                var lableIds=[makeid(),makeid(),makeid(),makeid()];

            /*  timeout[b] = setInterval(function() {            
                     this.setData(settings.url, settings.separator,lableIds);
                  }, 3000);*/
                $(this).createLayout(lableIds,settings.lableTag,settings.color,b);  

                $(this).setData(settings.url, settings.separator,lableIds);

            } else {
                test();
            }

        });
    }

    $.fn.createLayout = function(lables,lableTags,background,b) {

        console.log("inside createLayout");
        var timeDiv = makeid();
        var dataIds = [makeid(),makeid(),makeid(),makeid()];
        console.log("@CreateLayout : DataIds For Popup inputs :-"+dataIds);
        var buttonlist = makeid();

        var a = "<div class='row'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-10' style='background-color: "+background+";'>"
                +

                "<div class='row'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-12 timeline'>"
                +

                "<div class='col-md-6' id='"+timeDiv+"'></div>"
                +

                "<div class='col-md-6'>"
                + "<h4>Overall Latency : <lable id='latencyValue'></lable></h4>"
                + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class='row'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-12' id='Labels'>" + "<div class='row'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-12'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-6'><h4>Name : </h4></div>"
                + "<div class='col-md-6'><h4>Name :</h4></div>" + "</div>"
                + "</div>" + "<div class='row'>" + "<div class='col-md-12'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-6'>"
                + "<h4>"+ lableTags[0] +": <label id='"+lables[0]+"' /></label></h4>"
                + "</div>" + "<div class='col-md-6'>" + "<h4>"
                + lableTags[1]+" : <label id='"+lables[1]+"'></label>" + "</h4>" + "</div>"
                + "</div>" + "</div>" +

                "<div class='row'>" + "<div class='col-md-12'>"
                + "<div class='col-md-6'>" + "<h4>"
                + lableTags[2] +" : <label id='"+lables[2]+"'></label>" + "</h4>" + "</div>"
                + "<div class='col-md-6'>" + "<h4>"
                + lableTags[3] +" : <label id='"+lables[3]+"'></label>" + "</h4>" + "</div>"
                + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div></div>";
        this.append(a);




                var b = "<div class='col-md-2' id='"+buttonlist+"'"
                + "style='background-color: green;'>" + "<div align='center'>"
                + "<input class='button' type='button' id='editPopup'"
                + "onclick=getEditWindow('"+lables+"','"+dataIds+"') value='Edit'>" + "</div>"
                + "<div align='center'>"
                + "<input class='button' type='button' id='deletePopup'"
                + "onclick=getDeleteWindow('"+lables+"','"+dataIds+"') value='Delete'>" + "</div>"
                + "<div align='center'>"
                + "<input class='button' type='button' id='Active/Inactive'"
                + "value='Active' onclick=changeStat(this,'"+buttonlist+"','"+lables+"','"+b+"'); >" + "</div>"
                + "</div>" + "<div id='editc' style='display: none;'>"
                + "<form>"
                + "<input type='text' id='"+dataIds[0]+"'> <input type='text'"
                + "id='"+dataIds[1]+"' /> <input type='text' id='"+dataIds[2]+"' />"
                + " <input type='text' id='"+dataIds[3]+"' />" + "</form>" + "</div>"
                + "<div id='deletec' style='display: none;'>" + "<form>"
                + "<input type='text' id='a1data'> <input type='text'"
                + "id='b1data' /> <input type='text' id='c1data'/>"
                + "<input type='text' id='d1data' />" + "</form>"
                + "</div>";

        this.append(b);

        var auto = setInterval(function() {
            $('#'+timeDiv).load('time.jsp');
        }, 1000);
    }


    $.fn.setData = function(servlet_url, separator ,lables)
    {
        console.log('set data is called');
        console.log("@setData :lablel Id's :-"+lables);
        $.post(servlet_url, function(data) {

            var dataArray = data.split(separator);
            var ablock = dataArray[0];
            var bblock = dataArray[1];
            var cblock = dataArray[2];
            var dblock = dataArray[3];

            $("#"+lables[0]).text(ablock)
            $("#"+lables[1]).text(bblock);
            $("#"+lables[2]).text(cblock);
            $("#"+lables[3]).text(dblock);
            console.log("@setData : lable Ids :- "+document.getElementById(lables[0]));
        });
    }



    $.fn.getEditWindowjs = function(lables,dataIds)
    {
        console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+document.getElementById(lables[0]));
        console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+lables);
        console.log("@getEditWindow : content :- "+document.getElementById("content"));
        console.log("@getEditWindow : DataIds For Popup inputs :-"+dataIds);

            //$(function() {

                $('#editc').show();
                var a1 = (document.getElementById(lables[0]))? document.getElementById(lables[0]).innerHTML: "blank";//$('#'+lables[0]).html();
                var b1 = (document.getElementById(lables[1]))? document.getElementById(lables[1]).innerHTML: "blank";//$('#'+lables[1]).html();
                var c1 = (document.getElementById(lables[2]))? document.getElementById(lables[2]).innerHTML: "blank";//$('#'+lables[2]).html();
                var d1 = (document.getElementById(lables[3]))? document.getElementById(lables[3]).innerHTML: "blank";//$('#'+lables[3]).html();
                console.log(a1+", "+b1+", "+c1+", "+d1);
                $('#editc').dialog({

                    title : "Edit Label Data",
                    modal : true,
                    create : function(event, ui) {
                        $('#'+dataIds[0]).val("a1");
                        $('#'+dataIds[1]).val("b1");
                        $('#'+dataIds[2]).val("c1");
                        $('#'+dataIds[3]).val("d1");
                    },
                    buttons : {
                        SAVE : function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");

                        }
                    },
                }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "lavender");
            //  document.getElementById(dataIds[0]).value = ("a1");
                /*$('#'+dataIds[1]).val(b1);
                $('#'+dataIds[2]).val(c1);
                $('#'+dataIds[3]).val(d1);*/
            //});

    }
}(jQuery));



function changeStat(item,buttonlist,lables,b) {
    alert(b);
    alert(timeout);
    if (item.value == "Active") {

        item.value = 'InActive';    
        document.getElementById(buttonlist).style.background = "red";
        clearTimeout(timeout[b]);

    } else {

        item.value = "Active";
        document.getElementById(buttonlist).style.background = "green";

    }
}

function getEditWindow(lables,dataIds)
{
    console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+document.getElementById(lables[0]));
    console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+lables);
    console.log("@getEditWindow : content :- "+document.getElementById("content"));
    console.log("@getEditWindow : DataIds For Popup inputs :-"+dataIds);

    $(this).getEditWindowjs(lables,dataIds);
}


function getDeleteWindow(lables,dataIds) {
    console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+document.getElementById("'"+lables[0])+"'");
    console.log("@getEditWindow : lable Ids :- "+lables);
    $(function() {
        $("#deletec").show();
        var a = $('#'+lables[0]).html();
        var b = $('#'+lables[1]).html();
        var c = $('#'+lables[2]).html();
        var d = $('#'+lables[3]).html();

        $("#deletec").dialog({

            title : "Delete Label Data",
            moadal : true,
            create : function(event, ui) {
                $('#'+dataIds[0]).val(a);
                $('#'+dataIds[1]).val(b);
                $('#'+dataIds[2]).val(c);
                $('#'+dataIds[3]).val(d);
            },
            buttons : {
                DELETE : function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },

        });

    });

}

function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * (possible.length/6)));

    return text;
}

function randNum()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * (possible.length/6)));

    return text;
}

function test() {
    console.log('please pass the url and separator');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./js/test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="testUIload.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="number" id="ChannelNum" name="ChannelNum"> <input
            type="submit" value="Start Channel">

    </form>

    <%
        int number = 0;
        String num = "";

        if (request.getParameter("ChannelNum") != null) {
            num = request.getParameter("ChannelNum");
            number = Integer.parseInt(num);
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    %>
    <script>
$(document).ready( function(){  

    $("#content_<%=i%>").createComponent(
                            {
                                url : 'RandomDataGen',
                                separator : '|',
                                lableTag : [ 'Channel 1', 'Channel 2',
                                        'Channel 3', 'Channel 4' ],
                                color : 'grey'
                            });
                });
    </script>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="content" id="content_<%=i%>"></div>
    </div>
    <%
        }
        }
    %>



</body>
</html>
```

> servlet is working fine it responding random string with | separator so i >just removed it to increase code redability

Comment: That's a lot of code. Is all (any?) of that CSS relevant to what you're asking? It would help if you could reduce the code to the minimum needed to effectively demonstrate the issue.

Comment: An [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be more likely to attract help.